# Laravel many to many relational pivot table not being created

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

Have been working on a many to many relation of a laravel project. Here I have two tables `user_classes` & `promotional_notis`. Relation between them is many-to-many. For this in my `PromotionalNoti` model, I stated the following relation:

```
public function user_classes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(UserClass::class,'promo_notis_user_classes');
}
```

After migration, only `user_classes` & `promotional_notis` tables are being created. There is no pivot table. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: The Model will not create the table. You need to create it in your migration code.